# How to make where condition in view dynamic in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apps

Hi I have a view which has a where condition which is hard coded and want that condition to be dynamic which can pick hard coded values dynamically from another table
Below is the view:

```
create or replace view Dynamic_dist (location, district,map, source) as
select a.Location,
b.district_id,
a.map_loc
decode b.source('A1', 'AMZ',
                'B1', 'Bec',
                'C1', 'Cal',
                'D1', 'Dec') LOB
From Maps a, districts b 
WHERE a.Map_id = b.district_id
AND b.source IN ('A1',
                           'B1',
                           'C1',
                           'D1');
```

the values "A1, B1, C1, D1" to be taken from `select meaning from loc_area`

Please suggest how to take these values dynamically.

Comment: Is the replacement of "AND b.source IN ('A1','B1','C1','D1')" by "and b.source in (select meaning from loc_area)" what you want to have ?

Comment: yeah! something like AND b.source IN ('A1','B1','C1','D1')" by "and b.source in (select meaning from loc_area where meaning = :meaning)

Comment: Have you tried it ? what are the issues with it ?

Comment: hey @MaximBorunov actually we are not allowed to use parameter the query must be dynamic and there is  a change in query as well.

Comment: What about the following - you have the temporary table which is used in the view. You fill this temporary table before querying the view. The view has the condition like "and b.source in (select meaning from temporary_table)". Does it work for you ?

Comment: Is the translation for A1 to AMZ , B1 to Bec, ... is coming from another table loc_area? If so, you can join that in to get the translation, or put a select statement in the select list to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GTT table for filter and refer it in view.

For example:

```
create or replace view Dynamic_dist (location, district,map, source) as
select a.Location,
b.district_id,
a.map_loc,
decode b.source('A1', 'AMZ',
                'B1', 'Bec',
                'C1', 'Cal',
                'D1', 'Dec') LOB
From Maps a, districts b 
WHERE a.Map_id = b.district_id
AND b.source IN (select id from GTT_table);

insert into gtt_table values('A1');
insert into gtt_table values('B1');
insert into gtt_table values('C1');

select * from Dynamic_dis;
```